# How to secure json result from hijacking in ASPNet Core

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I need to secure my json responses from hijacking in aspnet core. I used to have a working solution in beta 8, but I cannot get that to work properly in 1.1.

What I want to do is to check whether a Json response is an enumerable or not. If it is, I wrap the enumerable in an object.

This is what I had in an override of JsonOutputFormatter:

```
public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterContext context)
{
    if (context.Object is IEnumerable)
    {
        context.Object = new { result = context.Object };
    }
    return base.WriteResponseBodyAsync(context);
}
```

This no longer works due to changes in the framework.

Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to wrap enumerable responses into an object to avoid hijacking?

Comment: just curious what do you mean by hijacking and how does wrapping the enumerable like that prevent it?

Comment: @JoeAudette My assumption is that he is referring to this hack: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/

Comment: thanks! very interesting, glad it doesn't work in modern browsers, but I guess it makes sense to mitigate it

Comment: @Steve: Isn't that like really old and as stated in the linked article only working for very old browsers? FF2? Who's using that Or IE 5.5?

Comment: looking at the source of [JsonOutputFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonOutputFormatter.cs) I see that it's WriteResponseBodyAsync takes 2 parameters, and that it inherits from [TextOutputFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Formatters/TextOutputFormatter.cs) which does have a method like that with one param, but it is sealed so you can't override that one. I think you need to add Encoding selectedEncoding to the method signature of your override

Comment: @Tseng It is but *I* don't know of any other vulnerability, to which the OP may be referring, that fits better. Until he/she answers Joe Audette's question, we can only assume.

Comment: OP here: Yes, I was referring to this link as Steve G mentioned: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/